# When is a view's superview set in ios?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am dealing with an issue where I need to set constraints for a subview to the superview. In the parent controller, I am adding the controller and view on a tap gesture (the parent View has already been presented on screen):

(I'm using Xamarin C#, but the code simply bridges to the Obj-C equivalent)..

```
//1. instantiate child controller
var eventDetail = new EventDetailController ();

//2. add child controller to self
AddChildViewController (eventDetail);

//3. add child controller's view to self.view
View.AddSubview (eventDetail.View);
```

In the child view controller's ViewWillAppear, I'd like to add AutoLayout constraints between the View and its Superview, but Superview is null at this point, is there a reason for this?

**When is the View's Superview get set?**

Comment: I can't speak for Xamarin, but it should be set when you add it as a subview.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Hmm.. based on the docs, perhaps the order is not gauranteed? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16 Makes it seem like ViewWillAppear is called **before** it's been added to the view hierarchy, and therefore superview might not yet be set...